# How do I automatically restart the countdown timer after it reaches 0?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find a way to restart my countdown timer at 2:00 again when it reaches 0:00. I don't know if I'm wrong, but it won't work.

```js
const startingMinutes = 2;
let time = startingMinutes * 60;

const countdownEl = document.getElementById('countdown');

setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000)

function updateCountdown(){
    const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
    let seconds = time % 60;
    
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
    

    countdownEl.innerHTML = `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
    time--;
    time = time < 0 ? 0 : time;
    if (time == 0) {
        fn();
        setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000)
        return;
    }
}
```

```html
<p id="countdown">2:00</p>
```

Comment: 2.00 Unix Time or your local time?

Comment: I need the timer to count down 2 minutes and restart by itself.

Comment: Make use of ```setInterval``` and set it to every 2 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reset your time:

Sample

```js
var startingMinutes = 2;
let time = startingMinutes * 60;

const countdownEl = document.getElementById('countdown');

setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000)

function updateCountdown() {
  const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
  let seconds = time % 60;

  seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;


  countdownEl.innerHTML = `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
  time--;
  time = time < 0 ? 0 : time;
  if (time == 0) {
    fn();
    time = startingMinutes * 60;
    return;
  }

  function fn() {
    console.log("timer reset");
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="countdown">2:00</p>
```

Comment: You forgot to change the length of setInterval

Comment: You’re creating a new setInterval inside another

Comment: I modified the timer.

Comment: Thank you very much))) It works now) Hooray

Answer (score 3):

Reset the time once it hits zero, and you don't need to call setInterval again. Also, by calling `updateCountdown()` directly we can avoid hardcoding `2:00` in the HTML.

```js
const startingMinutes = 2;
let time = startingMinutes * 60;

const countdownEl = document.getElementById('countdown');

function updateCountdown(){
    const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
    let seconds = time % 60;
    
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
    
    countdownEl.innerHTML = `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
    time--;
    time = time < 0 ? 0 : time;
    if (time == 0) {
        // fn(); <-- not sure what this is supposed to do, so I commented it out
        time = startingMinutes * 60; // reset counter
    }
}

setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000);
updateCountdown();
```

```html
<p id="countdown"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different methodology.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', ticker(120, countdown('countdown')))

function countdown(target) {
  let counter = document.getElementById(target)
  
  return (now) => {
    let minutes = Math.floor(now / 60)
    let seconds = Math.round((now / 60) % 1 * 60)

    seconds = seconds >= 0 && seconds < 10 ? seconds = '0'+seconds : seconds

    counter.textContent = minutes+':'+seconds
  }
}

function ticker(seconds, tick, step = 1000) {
  let now = seconds;
  
  (function next() {
    tick(now)

    now = now - 1 || seconds

    setTimeout(next, step)
  })()
}
```

```html
<p id="countdown">Loading...</p>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is what OP wants, this only counts seconds and not minutes

Comment: Question (title) asks how to automatically restart. So, this demonstrates that.